# How to deploy/store tkinter sqlite database in a server?

Tags: python, firebase, sqlite, tkinter, firebase-authentication

I have a login interface, I used tkinter and sqlite3 as database, everything works fine, in my data base stored locally in my PC I've created an username and password which i use to login, I would like to know if there is a way to store only my **sqlite.db** in a cloud or some server and i can still be able to login with my tkinter interface in any computer using my databese in the cloud.
this is what im using to connect my sqlite database locally and works smootly.

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('login_file.db')
c = conn.cursor()
user = entry_usuario.get()
contra = entry_contrasena.get()

c.execute('SELECT * FROM superusuario WHERE usuario = ? AND password = ?', (user, contra))

if c.fetchall():
    messagebox.showinfo(title='login correcto', message='usuario y contraseña correctos')
else:
    messagebox.showerror(tittle=None, message='Contraseña Incorrecta')

c.close()
```

Psdt: I was trying to use firebase authentication to link with my tkinter login interface, but i wasnt succesful with it (i dont know how to replace it), maybe i should use another server?, any advise please let me know, thanks in advance have a good day

Comment: When you say _"i can still be able to login with my tkinter interface in any computer using my database in the cloud."_ do you mean that you've first installed your tkinter interface on that computer? Or, are you wanting to serve the tkinter interface via the server too?

Comment: @BryanOakley I only want to save my sqlite database in a server, not all my tkinter interface app. I already have my sqlite data base working locally so it will be great to just keep it in a server, but if it isnt possible i should try another database which can be stored in a server, actually I´ve been trying firebase but i couldnt get it

Comment: sqlite is a file based database, with no inbuilt network server. So you would either need to write your own access server, with authentication, and host it on an AWS server (or similar). 
The only way to do this without a server side function is to host it on a remote network drive - and mount it on your pc; but to do that you leave your data exposed since sqlite data bases aren't password protected.

Comment: In that case, I recommend removing the tkinter code from the example. All you're really asking is how to serve a sqlite database from a server.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite is a file based database, with no in built network server. So your application needs to access it as a file in a known location.

The only way to do this without a server side function is to host it on a remote network drive - and mount it on your pc; but to do that you leave your data exposed since sqlite data bases aren't password protected in any form - anyone could download the database and open it.

To protect it you would need to implement a network server (maybe on an AWS server - or similar) which gave protected access and exposed the data as a REST API, or even better, don't use sqlite if you want a remote database.